# Does the Magnetic Flux change (at a point) If the wire which causes it was cutted into a half?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

If the electric charges move through a wire Does the generated Magnetic flux at any certain point chanage if this wire was cut into a half

Comment: Cut in which direction? Parallel to the current or across it? What happens to the current if the latter?

Comment: I mean if half the length of the wire is used instead of the whole wire

Comment: The answer is "yes" - any time you change the layout of the wire (length, diameter, shape) it will affect the field (although there may be points where it is the same, depending on the details) but recognize that you should really specify the geometry more carefully and in particular worry about how the current "returns" (it always has to be a loop...) if you want a "good" answer.

Comment: Ok but the rule we calculate the flux density at a point doesn't have the length of the wire in it it is equal to the permiability times current intensity over two times pi times the distance between the point and the center of the wire .. however the line should be with infinite length so is there another rule to calculate that which depends on the wire length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to learn about the [Biot-Savart Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/biosav.html#c1) which allows you to calculate the field at any point in space caused by an arbitrary current distribution. From the above link:

[image]

It basically describes the field $dB$ due to a current $I$ in a tiny wire of length $dL$; to get the value for a big wire you simply sum over all those littlewires. To really understand how to use it you need to appreciate integral calculus- but even if you don't, it helps to think of the current due to a long wires being the sum of the current due to many short wires.